# Tensorflow saved_model loader linux vs windows [update]

Tags: python, linux, windows, tensorflow

For some reason I'm getting errors loading back a saved model in Linux. For instance, I ran this on Python 3.5.4 and tensorflow 1.10.0 in an anaconda environment on Windows and it works, but then I run it on the same version of python and tensorflow and same conda version on linux mint and it doesn't work! It gives me this error message instead:

```
  File "<ipython-input-16-0689e9fe4aab>", line 4, in <module>
    path_to_model

  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/test3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 212, in load
    return loader.load(sess, tags, import_scope, **saver_kwargs)

  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/test3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 366, in load
    self.restore_variables(sess, saver, import_scope)

  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/test3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 318, in restore_variables
    saver.restore(sess, self._variables_path)

  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/test3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1717, in restore
    + compat.as_text(save_path))

"ValueError: The passed save_path is not a valid checkpoint: model/a/test1/variables/variables'"
```

Code:

```
path_to_model = 'model/a/test1/'

current_graph = tf.Graph()
current_session = tf.Session(graph = current_graph)

curr_meta_graph_definition = tf.saved_model.loader.load(
                                                           current_session,
                                                           [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                                                           path_to_model
                                                       )
```

UPDATE: I think the issue may actually be due to Linux vs. Windows. I noticed that I'm actually saving the model like so:

```
    export_path = os.path.join(
                                    tf.compat.as_bytes(self.path),
                                    tf.compat.as_bytes(str(iteration_val))
                                )

    self.builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)
    .....
```

Does anyone know if the tf.compat.as_bytes would act differently on Linux vs Windows? I noticed that models I save in Windows cannot be loaded back in Linux, but I can save and load the models if done in the same OS.

Comment: *`The passed save_path is not a valid checkpoint: model/a/test1/variables/variables'`*. Perhaps you should show your command line, and show your code and how you are handling `save_path`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! What do you mean by showing how I'm handling "save_path"? The thing is I'm not explicitly adding or modifying anything by the name of "save_path". The only code I'm running is what I displayed in my post. I'm running this in the Spyder IDE too